# Many strange font problems in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 and I have terrible font problems in a lot of applications. Often, digits don't appear at all, or they only appear when they are highlighted. Here's how the main Google Voice screen looks for me:

[image: Icons missing in Google Voice interface]

Here's a post on Google Keep:

[image]

Here's the same post with the text selected:

[image]

The digits are now visible, but their font is still clearly wrong.

Sometimes I have problems in applications like IntelliJ or Perforce. Some are completely unusable unless I can change their font settings.

Google Slides does something strange: in some documents, it shows the correct font an then the image jumps and the text is replaced by the wrong font. I checked and I have no extension that changes fonts. (I used to to fix the problem, but it only made it worse.) When I view the slides in presentation mode the fonts are correct again.

Does anyone have any idea of what's going on and how I can repair it?

Again, at this stage, I'd just like to completely reset my font system. Is there a way to do that:

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an application to reset Ubuntu. I focused on fonts. Removing one Chinese font solved the problem. That's all there was to it after all.